# QTouchEvent Ubuntu 14.04 vs RHEL 7.4

Tags: qt, rhel

When a touchscreen monitor is pressed, using Qt4.8, `viewportEvent(QEvent *event)` fires the correct signals (`QEvent::TouchBegin`, `QEvent::TouchUpdate`) on a PC with Ubuntu 14.04 installed.

For the exact same source code compiled on a PC running RHEL 7.4, only mouse events are returned.

*dmesg* and *lsusb* commands on both PCs return the same results, indicating to me no driver issues.

Why would RHEL not return the correct signals in this case? I wish to use multitouch on RHEL PCs.